# Order get_terms by count using a custom taxonomy hierarchy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

When I test get_terms with normal Wordpress posts it seems to be working. Maybe because I don't have hierarchy yet for these categories. But it doesn't work with WooCommerces custom taxonomy "product_cat" when ordering by anything. Im trying to order by count and it returns them by name.

These product categories are nested 3 layers deep in the category tree. Maybe that effects it?

`$cats = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'orderby' => 'count', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'number' => 5,
));
echo '<pre>'; print_r($cats); echo '</pre>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it's the best solution but I ended up using a custom query to show all categories ordered by count.

```
$cats = $wpdb->get_results("
    select tt.term_id, count, name, slug
    from ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy as tt
    inner join ".$wpdb->prefix."terms as terms
    on tt.term_id = terms.term_id
    where taxonomy = 'product_cat' 
    order by count desc limit 10
");
echo '<pre>'; print_r($cats); echo '</pre>';
```